# How to nest 2 for loops into one if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

How do you put 2 for loops inside an if statement?

```
Ships = [
    ["Aircraft Carrier", 5], 
    ["Battleship", 4], 
    ["Submarine", 3],    
    ["Destroyer", 3], 
    ["Patrol Boat", 2]
]
ships_left = ["A","B","S","D","P"]

if [ship for ship in ships_left name for name in Ships if name[0][0] == ship]:
    print(name[0])
```

Expected output:

```
Aircraft Carrier
```

This is because if they both iterate once then ship should be equal to `"A"` and name should be `["Aircraft Carrier", 5]`, so `name[0][0]` should be `"A"`.

How would you do this for it the code to independently iterate through both lists and branch on a given is statement associating the two lists?

Comment: Can you provide us the expected output ?

Comment: Can you explain the logic and what you want as output, why iterate over all ships if you just want the first match?

Comment: What is the condition you are testing?  What does "*actually work*" mean?  You have not told us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I mean for 2 for statements to be nested and referenced inside one if statement, on one line. The actual circumstance of ships and ships_left does not matter, I'm just looking how to iterate through two given lists in one line using 2 for loops that are contained within an if statement

Answer (score 2):

Calculate what ships are left *first*, before using `if` to test if there were any:

```
left_names = [name for name, size in Ships if name[0] in ships_left]
if left_names:
    print(left_names[0])
```

By calculating what ships are left first, you can re-use the result for both the `if` test and the `print()` function; otherwise you'd have to make the same calculation twice.

You also don't need two loops; you only need to loop over your `Ships` list and test each name against the `ships_left` list. I'd make `ships_left` a set, however, for faster membership testing:

```
ships_left = {"A", "B", "S", "D", "P"}
```

Membership testing in a list takes up to N steps (where N is the length of the list), while in a set membership testing takes constant time (O(1)). This makes removing a ship once it's been sunk (or placed on the board) easy and fast too:

```
ships_left.remove(name[0])
```

You could use the `next()` function with a generator expression if you only need the *first* match; this avoids extracting all names:

```
ship_left = next((name for name, size in Ships if name[0] in ships_left), None)
if ship_left:
    print(ship_left)
```

Demo:

```
>>> Ships = [
...     ["Aircraft Carrier", 5],
...     ["Battleship", 4],
...     ["Submarine", 3],
...     ["Destroyer", 3],
...     ["Patrol Boat", 2]
... ]
>>> ships_left = {"A", "B", "S", "D", "P"}
>>> next((name for name, size in Ships if name[0] in ships_left), None)
'Aircraft Carrier'
>>> ships_left.remove('A')
>>> next((name for name, size in Ships if name[0] in ships_left), None)
'Battleship'
>>> ships_left.clear()  # remove all ships
>>> next((name for name, size in Ships if name[0] in ships_left), None) is None
True
```

Comment: I wasn't the one who down-voted, but what I'm looking for is a way to put two for statements in one line because I want it to be more compact, plus I cant create any more variables in this program

Comment: @Frostyfeet: two for statements *makes no sense* for your requirements. You'd end up producing the product of the two lists, testing each name in one against all names in the other. That's extremely inefficient, and is not needed at all.

Comment: @Frostyfeet: and if you put the loop in your `if` statement, you'd have to do the *same loop again* to be able to print the matching name. This is what variables are great at, to store a result so you don't have to calculate it again.

Comment: Why do you want it to be more compact?  Compact is often obscure, never faster, and sometimes slower.